# Moving components in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have the following component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Canvas  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="16" height="16" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Image;       
            public function init(i:Number):void {
                this.setStyle("backgroundColor", userFrame.colors[i]);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Image x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16" 
        source="@Embed(source='../border16x16.png')"/>

    </mx:Canvas>
```

I then add it to the stage with `addChild(block)`
Then I want to move it by altering `block.x` which fails. How can I change my code to implement the moving effect?

Comment: What is the layout of the parent adding the child?

Comment: you meen <mx:Application applicationComplete="init()" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="600" height="500" xmlns:ns1="*"> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a variable, or component, named `block` in your sample, so I'm unclear what you're trying to move.

If you want to move the image, first you'll have to give it an ID:

```
<mx:Image id="myImage" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16" source="@Embed(source='../border16x16.png')"/>
```

And then at some point, just change the x and y values to move it:

```
myImage.x = newXValue;
myImage.y = newYValue;
```

You can also use the move method:

```
myImage.move(newXValue, newYValue);
```

Keep in mind that x and y values are ignored in some Flex MX containers, such as HBox or VBox and in some Flex 4 Spark layouts, such as HorizontalLayout and VerticalLayout.  In Spark, be sure to use a Basic Layout if you want to position elements using x and y.  In Flex 3, be sure to use a container or a canvas for basic layout.